# Exception "A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of" when posting data using request()

Tags: python, json, post, parameters, python-requests

I am planning to send request to server with the following code. I have spent more than 1 day to resolve this but without any progress. And please forgive me I have to hide the real URL address becuase of Company Security Policy.

```
import requests

get_ci = requests.session()

get_ci_url = 'https://this_is_a_fake_URL_to_paste_in_stackoverflow.JSON'
get_ci_param_dict = {"Username": "fake","Password": "fakefakefake","CIType": "system","CIID": "sampleid","CIName": "","AttrFilter": "","SubObjFilter": ""}
get_ci_param_str = str(get_ci_param_dict)

print(get_ci_param_dict)
print(get_ci_param_str)

get_ci_result = get_ci.request('POST', url=get_ci_url, params=get_ci_param_str, verify=False)

print(get_ci_result.status_code)
print(get_ci_result.text)
```

And what I get in the Run result is,

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/this/is/the/fake/path/Test_02.py
{'CIID': 'sampleid', 'CIType': 'system', 'AttrFilter': '', 'Password': 'fake', 'CIName': '', 'Username': 'fake', 'SubObjFilter': ''}
{'CIID': 'sampleid', 'CIType': 'system', 'AttrFilter': '', 'Password': 'fake', 'CIName': '', 'Username': 'fake', 'SubObjFilter': ''}
C:\Python34\lib\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:843: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
500
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">*org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of* </ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

More tips,

1. I have contact the Server Code Developer - They only need is a
   string in a JSON format sent in a "Parameter" way. Which means it
   is correct to use `params` in `request()`.
2. I have tried with `dumps.json(get_ci_param_dict)` => The same result.
3. It has returned the 200 code when I only request the server's root,
       which proves me the url is ok.

---

Additional Logs when update the `params` to `data`.

```
C:\Python34\lib\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:843: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
500
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.61 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - 1</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>1</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    com.fake.security.XSSHttpReuquestWrapper.GeneralParameters(XSSHttpReuquestWrapper.java:158)
    com.fake.security.XSSHttpReuquestWrapper.checkParameter(XSSHttpReuquestWrapper.java:101)
    com.fake.security.XSSHttpReuquestWrapper.validateParameter(XSSHttpReuquestWrapper.java:142)
    com.fake.security.XSSSecurityFilter.doFilter(XSSSecurityFilter.java:35)
    com.fake.webservice.interceptor.GetContextFilter.doFilter(GetContextFilter.java:24)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.61 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.61</h3></body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

FINAL SOLUTION FOR THIS QUESTION

@e4c5 your suggestion is helpful to figure out the final solution. The `param` should be sent to server via `data`, as the `data` should be sent out as dict or byte as defined in the offical document, so need use `param` as the dict key to send. Please see the code as below,

```
import requests
import json


get_ci_url = 'https://sample.fake.com:0000/sample/fake/fakeagain.JSON'
get_ci_param_dict = {"Username": "fake","Password": "fakefake".......}
get_ci_param_json = json.dumps(get_ci_param_dict)

params = {'param': get_ci_param_json}

get_ci_result = requests.request('POST', url=get_ci_url, data=params, verify=False)

print(get_ci_result.status_code)
print(get_ci_result.text)
```

ROOT CAUSE:`param` should be sent via `data` parameter. Official Document has clearly state that => :param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.

Thanks My colleauge - Mr.J and @e4c5's great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if what your server expects is json, you should use the json parameter to python requests

```
get_ci_result = get_ci.request('POST', url=get_ci_url,  
    json=get_ci_param_dict, verify=False)
```

also note that the `params` parameter is usually used with get (and is used to format the query string of a URL), with post and form data it should be `data` and a dictionary again.

For additional information please refer to : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/

Comment: Thanks very much for @e4c5 to answer my 1st question on SO. But for the question itself. 1) I have tried use both 'data' and 'json' before, the server returned another exception which told me 'params' is required in the request when using 'json', will met the same error when using 'data'. 2) This is also consistent of my TIP1) - "Send string in JSON format" in 'params' way per confirmed the server side developer. 3) Actually the POST request is getting a data from server, what I sent in 'params' is the Query thing when I use SOAPUI.

Comment: Sorry, the 1st comment should be deleted. I was trying to start a 2nd line instead of posting the comment when press 'Enter' button. :)

Comment: Nopes, you have completely misunderstood python-requests. What's sent in params will not appear as POST data the server. Youc an refer to the documentation to confirm these facts for yourself

Comment: I have tried with `json` and `data` both, but met the parameters missing exception as I said. Also I have tried `GET` method was told `GET` method is not supported by the server.

Comment: you need to understand that `parameter` is a broader term. the server is not referring to the `param` *parameter* you are using in request. `json` is the correct **parameter** to use. The problem here is that you are sending the wrong **parameters** via your json dictionary to the server. For that you need to ask another question or look at the **parameters** expected by the server. Here your **paramters** are Username, fakefakefake etc

Comment: Thanks again for your patience. I will keep post here when solution identified.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary of data will automatically be `form-encoded` when the request is made. Use `json` parameter when the server accepts JSON-Encoded POST/PATCH data instead of `form-encoded` data.

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to application/json.

Visit https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#More-complicated-POST-requests

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem.

Even though my data was already a dictionary I needed to json.dumps(data) again:

```
response = requests.post(url = url ,headers=head,data = json.dumps(data))
```

I just wanted to share this in case somebody has a similar problem.